# Create an instance of a class inside its own self

Tags: ios, swift

Here's the situation.
I have a swift model class file that contains all the variables for a weather forecast (min temperature, max temperature, humidity, etc).
The class also contains the function that downloads all the data from the API.
My question is, is it possible to create an array of the class inside the class itself, so that I can append a number of objects (of the same class itself) based on the number of days of forecast the API sends back?
If so, can you tell me how it could be achieved?
The other option I have that totally works, is to do the API downloading and parsing outside of the forecast class (in the ViewController) but that would make my ViewController messy.

Comment: Yes, you can do this. You would probably make the `getForecast` function a class function. There is no trick to the syntax. Simply create an array as you would normally

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing preventing you from referencing a class name within its definition.  So you can do something like this:

```
class Foo {
    var boz = [Foo]() // you can append to this array as needed
}
```

Comment: For some reason I keep getting Thread: EXEC_BAD_ACCESS error at the let bar = Foo() line.

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry about that.  During initialization if you init like that it goes into an infinite loop as the first Foo tries to initialize bar and the next one tries to init bar and so on.  I've edited the answer to remove that line, you can still have an array of Foo (variable boz), you just have to add to it after the initial class is created.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call the API to get all the weather's datas in your model but in a dedicated class.
Also, you shouldn't parse and store the datas inside your model.

In your model, you only need to have all the attributes of your object and methods.

Maybe you can create an Helper class where you implements all this methods and store the datas.

Comment: So basically it's a better practice to create a helper class that would parse the JSON and store the data in an array and then I get to call that helper class in my ViewController to update my UI?

Comment: Exactly. By doing this you respect the OOP. And you code will be easily maintable and readable. Apologize for my english.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense.
I have an off-topic question. Do you know a good resource for best practices like what you've mentioned.